# Kalman Filter to improve sensor reading without prediction

Tags: kalman-filter

Does a Kalman filter have any applications towards a problem that doesn't involve temporal prediction, but rather just improving the estimation of something's position using two sensors.

Say I have two sensors observing an object and know the noise distribution of those errors - could I use a kalman filter to improve the reading? What benefits would it offer other than just multiplying the gaussian distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Kalman filter can be used for estimating the current state of a system as well as for predicting future states.  It can also be used in situations where the dynamical model is simply that the state is (an unknown) constant and the observations are direct measurements of the state.

However, if you simplify the Kalman filter down to this level, you end up with a scheme that is no different from maximum likelihood estimation of the unknown state, so the Kalman filter isn't doing anything particularly interesting in this case.

Comment: It's a good exercise to simplify the Kalman filter equations for this case and see that you're getting exactly the MLE that you would get by conventional methods.